# Can we choose another edge form for loop edge type or child-parent edge?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Example 1:

```
elements: [{
      data: {
        id: 'a'
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: 'b',
        parent: 'a'
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: 'ab',
        source: 'b',
        target: 'a'
      }
    }
  ],
  style: [{
    selector: 'edge',
    css: {
      'curve-style': 'bezier',
      'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
    }
  }]
```

I'm trying to draw edge from node to its parent.
I'm expecting to have straight line from the node to the outer frame like this:

[image]

But instead I got a curved line like this:

[image]

Example 2:

If I try to make an edge with the same source and target, it's form is always a curved line (like loop edge type in edge type demo).

Even if I choose curve-style like this:

```
cy.add([{
    data: {
        "source": guid,
        "target": guid,
    },
    style: {
        "curve-style": "bezier",
        "source-endpoint": '0% 0%',
        "target-endpoint": '0% -80%'
    },
}])
```

I get curved line like this:

[image: 1]

The same works for straight curve-style.

How can I draw another edge form for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it's possible without forking cytoscape.js, but I could be wrong.

https://codepen.io/Raven0us/pen/yLYZbJx

Here's a workaround, using a ghost node that never gets displayed.

```js
cy.$('edge.with-compound').forEach((edge, i) => {
    // parent node is edge source
    let position = calculateGhostNodePosition(edge.source());

    // ghost node id needs to keep a reference to the node that was used to calculate its position
    let ghostNodeId = `ghost-${edge.source().id}`;
    cy.add({
        group: 'nodes',
        data: {
            id: ghostNodeId
        },
        position: {
            x: position.x,
            y: position.y
        },
        classes: ['ghost-node']
    });

    cy.add({
        group: 'edges',
        data: {
            id: `${ghostNodeId}-edge`,
            source: edge.data('target'),
            target: ghostNodeId,
            classes: ['ghost-node-connector']
        }
    })
})

cy.$('node[parent]').on('position', e => {
    let node = e.target;
    let targetGhostNode = cy.$(`node[id="ghost-${node.id}"]`);

    let position = calculateGhostNodePosition(node);

    targetGhostNode.position({
        x: position.x,
        y: position.y
    })
})

/**
 *
 * @param sourceNode
 * @returns {{x: number | SVGAnimatedLength, y: *}}
 */
function calculateGhostNodePosition(sourceNode) {
    let boundingBox = sourceNode.boundingBox();

    // you need to actually calculate these and take node size in account
    let x = boundingBox.x1;
    let y = boundingBox.y1 + ((boundingBox.y2 - boundingBox.y1) / 2) + 8;

    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    }
}
```

Ghost node position is not properly calculated, you can obtain that from the compound node bounding box. 
This way, you have full control over the edge. Additionally, when exporting the network, you should consider discarding the "assisting edges", because based on the network's data, you should always be able to redraw those.

PS - If compound node is getting dragged around, you also need to recalculate ghost node position.

Comment: Thank you! This could be a solution. 

But still I have difficulties with recalculating ghost node position. So if I drag the parent, the node and ghost node move together. But if I drag the main node, ghost node doesn't move. Can't find the proper example in cytoscape demos.

Maybe you know an example of recalculating a node's position after another node? I'm quite new to cytoscape, sorry(

Comment: You need to add a `grab` listener to compound nodes. Do you still need this?

Comment: Yeah, still need it. Tried to find a good example by myself, but I would be grateful if you show me an example